# Airflow: Create an Operator which return either a sensor or a DummyOperator based on a hook result

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-composer, airflow

I would like to know if there is a way to build an Operator that perform a pub/sub hook (or another hook) which would fail if the object already exists. 
If this hook returns an Exception then we action a Sensor or continue the DAG if not.

I tried to implement that with the following metacode in mind but could not made it yet.

```py
class CheckIfExistOperator(BaseOperator):
    def execute(self, context):
        try:
            PubSubHook(
                ...
            ).create_subscription(
                ...
                fail_if_exists=True
            )
            return DummyOperator(
                task_id='subscriber_already_exists',
                ...
                )
        except PubSubException as e:
            return PubSubPullSensor(
               ...
            )
```

Any suggestions? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you need some kind of branching. 
In the example below I used a `BranchPythonOperator` to execute a function that tries to create a new subscription and return a string informing if the task succeeded or failed. After that I used two `PythonOperators` with task_id's corresponding to the strings returned by the BranchPythonOperator and defined a dependency between **start_op** and the **success** and **fail** tasks

```
from airflow.contrib.hooks import gcp_pubsub_hook
from airflow.operators import python_operator
from airflow import models

def print_context1(ds, **kwargs):
    return 'THE TASK SUCCEDED'

def print_context2(ds, **kwargs):
    return 'THE TASK FAILED'

def start_function(ds, **kwargs):
    try:        
        response = gcp_pubsub_hook.PubSubHook().create_subscription(
        topic_project="my-project",
        topic="beam",
        subscription="beam_sub2",
        subscription_project=None, 
        ack_deadline_secs=10,
        fail_if_exists=True)
        return "succeeded"
    except gcp_pubsub_hook.PubSubException:
        return "failed"


default_dag_args = {
...
}

with models.DAG(
        'pubsub_airflow',
        default_args=default_dag_args) as dag:

    start_op = python_operator.BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id='start',
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=start_function
    )

    success = python_operator.PythonOperator(
        task_id='succeeded',
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=print_context1
    )

    fail = python_operator.PythonOperator(
        task_id='failed',
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=print_context2
    )

    start_op >> [success,fail]
```

In your case, you could use this code as a base and replace the two `PythonOperators` with your DummyOperator and your sensor.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I'd read this as non-Pythonic and not what Airflow expects. I'd be very surprised if you could get this pattern to work. I just want to be clear that I recommend rethinking the problem with more Python and Airflow in mind.

Airflow does have a branching pattern in it natively and recommends using it as part of its key concepts... [here are the docs where I'd recommend you start](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=branch#branching). It will give you all of the actual end features you want.